# How to add more than one cloudbit?

Tags: javascript

How can I add another Cloudbit into the code here? I've tried running these codes but it's still not working. Or is it my cloudbit is faulty?

**JS Code**

```
var authToken = "d31ad307a04a7e545e4a6ebdcf95ae2ce670aba107f5e2f7ef50df8e6a32188e";
var deviceIdA = "00e04c034276";
var deviceIdB= "00e04c037cdd";



setInterval(checkInputA,1000);
setInterval(checkInputB,1000);


function activateOutputA(percentValue,durationMs)
{ 
    //call the function postOutput  to post output
    postOutputA(percentValue,durationMs); 
}
function activateOutputB(percentValue,durationMs)
{ 
    //call the function postOutput  to post output
    postOutputB(percentValue,durationMs); 
}
function start()
{ 
    //call the functions getInput
    getInputA();
    getInputB();
}

function checkInputA()
{
    if(percentA>50)
    {
    activateOutputA(100,3000);
    }
}
function checkInputB()
{
    if(percentB>50)
    {
    activateOutputB(100,3000);
    }   
}
```

**HTTP code**

```
var percentA=0;
var percentB=0;

function postOutputA(percentValue,durationMs) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "https://api-http.littlebitscloud.cc/devices/"+deviceIdA+"/output", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+authToken);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/vnd.littlebits.v2+json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

    var params = JSON.stringify({percentA: percentValueA, duration_msA: durationMsA});
    req.send(params);
}
function postOutputB(percentValue,durationMs) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "https://api-http.littlebitscloud.cc/devices/"+deviceIdB+"/output", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+authToken);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/vnd.littlebits.v2+json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

    var params = JSON.stringify({percentB: percentValueB, duration_msB: durationMsB});
    req.send(params);
}


function getInputA() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onprogress = function(progress) {
        var splittedData = progress.target.responseText.split("data:");
        var splitLength = splittedData.length;
        var latestResponse  = splittedData[splitLength-1];

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(latestResponse);
        percentA = jsonObj.payload.percent;
    }

    req.open("GET", "https://api-http.littlebitscloud.cc/devices/"+deviceIdA+"/input", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+authToken);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/vnd.littlebits.v2+json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    req.send();
}
function getInputB() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onprogress = function(progress) {
        var splittedData = progress.target.responseText.split("data:");
        var splitLength = splittedData.length;
        var latestResponse  = splittedData[splitLength-1];

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(latestResponse);
        percentB = jsonObj.payload.percent;
    }

    req.open("GET", "https://api-http.littlebitscloud.cc/devices/"+deviceIdB+"/input", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+authToken);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/vnd.littlebits.v2+json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    req.send();
}
```

PS : I'm a fresh student studying about these code & also new to StackOverFlow. Sorry.

Comment: why did you tag java?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, Sorry, i'm new to the website. I tried to put it, but they said there's error.


PS: I'm a fresh student studying about java.

Comment: @AnkitSharma isn't this under JAVA? I need to edit the JavaScript and HTTP.

Comment: @VexasoeeJohnson I accessing SO from office here these links are blocked this may happen to lot of users if you post in SO itself the you will get response  quickly

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Sorry, i've edited.

Comment: @VexasoeeJohnson JavaScript is not Java that's why ;) its 2 distinct things. Your code is clearly JavaScript so you have to tag your question right to get answers faster.

Comment: is this code part of intel smart home solution?